# How to change the tab style for buffered tabs

Tags: jedit

How can I change the look and feel of the buffered tabs plugin to make them look like normal tabs instead of a ribbon?

[image]

Comment: When I install the plugin they look like normal tabs to me, sure you have it installed?

Comment: @TomPower: Hi I just updated the ask with a screen shot.  Can you verify this is what you are seeing?

Comment: No I see normal tabs, but don't see an option to control that, did you try the users mailing list yet? https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/jedit-users

Comment: Tom Power are you on Mac OS like JaJ? Or at least the screenshot looks to me like JaJ is on Mac OS.

Comment: @Vampire Yes I'm on a mac.  I have used jedit on windows and my tabs looked normal on win7.

Comment: @TomPower: Hi I haven't reached out to the mailing list but I will try to do so sometime today.  thx.  But yes, I am using a mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use jEdit on a Mac, it uses the Mac Look and Feel to be more familiar to people working on Macs. What you see is the standard appearance of Tabs on a Mac. The Tabs design depends on the Look and Feel that you select. You can change the Look and Feel at any time, simply by changing it in the Global Settings under Appearance. By changing the Look and Feel, you will also change the appearance of the Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, MacOS X has several types of tabs. For example, Safari and TexMate use "normal" tabs to work. Also, Intellij IDEA uses "normal" tabs with MacOS Look and Feel ([a link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/img/version13/smart_1_anim.gif)). I think it can be an item to investigate for jEdit developers.